# Считывание текстового файла

Tags: c#, текст

Возникла такая проблема: код запускается, но не считывает текстовый файл, тем более не создает новый. Подскажите как можно изменить...

```
public static void Main()
{
    string path = @"NewFile.txt";

    if (!File.Exists(path))
    {
        string[] createText = { "Hello", "And", "Welcome" };
        File.WriteAllLines(path, createText);
    }
    string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path);
    for (int i = 0; i < readText.Length; i++)
    {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (char ch in readText[i])
        {
            if (Char.IsLetter(ch))
            {             
                if (Char.IsUpper(ch))
                    builder.Append(Char.ToLower(ch));
                else
                    builder.Append(Char.ToUpper(ch));
            }
            else
            {
                builder.Append(ch);
            }
        }
        readText[i] = builder.ToString();
    }
    File.WriteAllLines(path, readText);
    Console.ReadLine ();
```

}

Comment: Запустил у себя, все работает, только пропустили `;` в строке `string[] readText = File.ReadAllLines(path)` и `}` в конце

Comment: @RusArt подправила. У вас и считывает файл и меняет регистр?

Comment: @Ольга все работает, только что проверил, https://i.imgur.com/ZeislMD.png

Comment: @PavelFedorov, да, убедилась, все работает.

Comment: @PavelFedorov А что тогда надо добавить, чтобы этот текст он записывал в новый файл?

Comment: @Ольга логично же, что изменить имя файла, если вы хотите в другой файл. В последней строке `File.WriteAllLines`

Comment: @PavelFedorov, спасибо, простите за глупый вопрос)))